# How to shorten my output? Currently getting 'inf'

Tags: c++, math, derivative

I'm writing a program to calculate the 'Taylor Series' and I'm getting 'inf' as my output. I'm not done with the program and everything isn't working properly yet, but I want to be able to see my output. Is there a way to shorten the output or make it visible? Thanks for the help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

long double taylorSeries(long double input, int degree);
long int factorial(int input);
long double derivative(long double input);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    long double taylorInput = cos(0);    

    cout << taylorSeries(taylorInput, 3) << endl;

    return 0;
}

// taylor series function
long double taylorSeries(long double input, int degree){

    long double i = 0;
    long double accumulation = 0;


    while (i < degree) {
        derivative(input);
        accumulation += (pow(input, i))/factorial(i); 
        i++;
    }

    return accumulation;
}

// function to calculate factorial
long int factorial(int input){

    long int factorial = 0;

    if (input == 1) {
        factorial = 0;
    }

    while (input > 0) {
        if (factorial == 0) {
            factorial = input * (input - 1);
            input -= 2;
        }

        else if (input > 0) {
            factorial *= input;
            input--;
        }


    }
    return factorial;
}

long double derivative(long double input){
     long double derivativeResult = 0;

    derivativeResult = (((input + .001) - (input)) / .001);

    return derivativeResult;
}
```

Comment: I am  not sure I understand what you mean by _shorten the output_. Have you tried performing the calculation step by step (e.g. in a debugger, or using print commands inserted after each iteration), to see at what point the values turn to infinity?

Comment: Why don't you put in a few more `cout` statements - e.g. one in derivative showing the `input` and `derivativeResult`, one in `factorial` etc. - you should be able to pinpoint when your result gets so large it hits "infinity" (i.e. can't be stored in the long double)... then you can think about whether that's inherent in the problem you have to solve (in which case you can give up for find an arbitrary precision library - lots of separate stackoverflow questions about that), you've made a mistake, or you can calculate it another way that avoids huge intermediate values....

Comment: Use the debugger to see the incremental steps.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I was originally doing that and was getting normal answers. Then all of a sudden was getting 'inf' so I assumed the answer was just going to be large. By shorten, I meant a smaller length of numbers.

Comment: The factorial function doesn't calculate the factorial properly for 0 nor 1, you should take a look at that first, since you rely on that function for the other one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `accumulation += (pow(input, i))/factorial(i);` you are dividing by 0.

On the factorial function you are missing the case for 0, factorial of 0 is 1.

EDIT: Factorial of 1 is also not 0, you should take a look at that factorial function first before going forward.

Answer (score 3):

Your factorial function is a bit screwy. Try this:

```
long factorial( long input ) {
    long output = 1;
    for( long i = 2; i <= input; ++ i ) {
        output *= i;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The double value `inf` is a special value to avoid losing information about an overflowing intermediate calculation when doing a subsequent math operation.  Once a chain of operations produces `inf` it will "stick" rather than producing a valid number that is an incorrect value.

A common way to get `inf` is to divide by zero in an environment where that's not a floating point exception.  So `x = 1.0 / 0.0 ... (any operations here)` will be `inf` because of the initial `inf`.  You have to find the problem calculation and eliminate it before you can see the rest of your result.